# Booklet Printing in MS Word with Epson Printer

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have been trying to print a booklet but for some unknown reason, the printer is outputing 2 empty pages at the end.

The document is 22 pages and therefore page 22 should be at the back.

[image]

When printed and folded, page 22 is inside followed by 2 empty pages.

Can anyone shed any light on how to rectify this?

---

**Microsoft Office Version:** Ofice 365

**Printer:** Epson XP-830

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an empty page at the end?

Comment: Does the document terminate with a table that reaches to the end of the page? Word will in this case will add an empty paragraph after the table, and there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Next: In the Page Setup dialog, Layout tab, is Section start set to Continuous?

Comment: And, if you click "Show/Hide" at the top right corner of the Paragraph group, do you any funny stuff at the end of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With booklet printing, each sheet has four page images and the pages are sequenced to read correctly once they are folded and stacked.  So all booklets will be some multiple of four pages.  With 22 actual pages, it needs two blank pages as placeholders since it is accomplished using whole sheets of paper.

Comment: I didn't think about that.  4 pages to a sheet, with 22 pages, you need 6 sheets (24 pages) leaving 2 pages blank at the end.